# LaTeX algorithmic package: Undefined Control Sequence in for-Loop

Tags: macros, errors, algorithms, loops

I'm trying to specify an algorithm in pseudocode in a LaTeX document, but I'm having trouble with the for-Loop. My statement:

```
\for{$bin=0 to binCount$}
\item blablabla
\endfor
```

keeps on generating the error **"Undefined Control Sequence"**. I also tried the usual for-notation (`bin=0;bin&lt;binCount;bin++`).
I have not defined any of the variables before, nor do I want to do that; I just want LaTeX to print exactly what I'm writing in an algorithm layout.

**Is there a way to "switch off" this sort of code interpretation? What exactly am I doing wrong?**

Add'l information: I have stated bot the algortihm and `algorithm` environment. Without this for-Loop, it generates the document without any errors. The `\item` statement is just a filler.

Comment: i think you shuold be using `\state` instead of `\item`

Answer (score 7):

Command names in LaTeX are case sensitive:

```
\FOR{$\mathit{bin}=0$ to $\mathit{binCount}$}
...
\ENDFOR
```

is what the documentation says (I added the `\mathit` around the multiletter variables, that renders better than writing `$binCount$`).

Comment: egregs solution (and example) is not working for me. I also added the package `algpseudocode` \usepackage{algorithmicx} \usepackage{algpseudocode}