# Undefined Control Sequence \For, \state, or \EndFor

Tags: loops, pseudocode, algorithmic

I want to write this algorithm but the error **Undefined Control Sequence \For, \state, or \EndFor** pops up.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithmic}[H]
     \KwData{Given the M detected objects}
     \KwResult{new clusters}
     \For (each object $i$)
        \state Create new cluster $C_i$;
        \state Initialize the cluster feature;
        \state $cluster Feature(i) = (x_i, y_i, v_{xi}, v_{yi}, 1, 0, i)$;
     \EndFor
     \caption{Initialization}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

I saw related questions but the case wasn't as mine.

[Undefined control sequence \State \COMMENT](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46827/undefined-control-sequence-state-comment)

[LaTeX algorithmic package: Undefined Control Sequence in for-Loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31826/latex-algorithmic-package-undefined-control-sequence-in-for-loop)

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The error message shows `\State` but your code shows `\state` (lowercase). What's right?

Comment: It is the same whether i used `state` or `State`.

Comment: Is `algpseudocode` a known package?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the `algorithmicx` package bundle.

Comment: Yes, but it is inside `algorithmic`. I saw it in many examples.

Comment: I can't create a for loop in the algorithm. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up commands from the packages `algorithm2e` and `algorithm`. Well, I believe you do.

See my following MWE. This does compile and uses the syntax provided by [the documentation here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e).

Is this what you wanted to type?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[titlepage,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
     \KwData{Given the M detected objects}
     \KwResult{new clusters}
     \For{each object $i$}{
        Create new cluster $C_i$\;
        Initialize the cluster feature\;
        $\mathit{cluster Feature}(i) = (x_i, y_i, v_{xi}, v_{yi}, 1, 0, i)$\;
                }
     \caption{Initialization}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But why my version didn't work, although i am using the documentation in here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms

Comment: PLease see the headings on this wikipage. You took code from "Typesetting using the algorithmicx package". I took code from "Typesetting using the algorithm2e package". Please read the documentation I linked in my answer. Seems to be a good one, as I was able to use it in a few minutes (and never heard of the package before...)

Answer (score 1):

This uses algoritmm

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[titlepage,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
     \caption{Initialization}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \Require  Given the M detected objects
     \Ensure new clusters
     \For {(each object $i$)}
        \State Create new cluster $C_i$;
        \State Initialize the cluster feature;
        \State $cluster Feature(i) = (x_i, y_i, v_{xi}, v_{yi}, 1, 0, i)$;
     \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```